# Retrieve all dimensionSetLines for all SalesOrders

Tags: dynamics-business-central

Is it possible to retrieve dimensionSetLines for all SalesOrders in one request using  Business Central API.
Not just retrieve dimensionSetLines for a specific SalesOrder but for all of them.

I wanted to know if this is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't retrieve the Dimension Set Lines directly. You have to go through the parent i.e., the Sales Orders.

However you can still retrieve the required data in one API-call with some clever usage of the OData protocol:

- `$select` to limit the number of fields retrieved for each Sales Order.
- `$expand` to include the Dimension Set Lines in the call to the Sales Orders endpoint.

An example of the API call could be as follows (using REST Client in Visual Studio Code):

```
@auth = Bearer [Access Token]

GET https://api.businesscentral.dynamics.com/v2.0/[Tenant ID]/[Environment Name]/api/v2.0/salesOrders?$select=id,number&$expand=dimensionSetLines
Company: [Company Name]
Authorization: {{auth}}
```